# JavaScript, HTML : "window.location.replace then alert" not working in order

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a web page that runs a JavaScript function at a certain time. The function should move the webpage to a `about:blank` page and alert that the web page is expired. I get the function to be executed at the time that I want, but the function execute alert part and then move the page. If alert pops up before `window.location.replace`, the users are still able to see the webpage. I want the webpage to move to `about:blank` page first, then alert the user that the web page is expired. The following is my code.

```
<SCRIPT>
    function checkExpiry() {
        var now_ = new Date();
        var expiry = new Date("<?php echo $expiry ?>")
        if (now_ > expiry) {
            window.location.replace("about:blank");
            alert("The webpage is expired.");
        }            
    }
    setInterval(function () { checkExpiry(); }, 15 * 1000);
</SCRIPT>
```

The function properly runs every 15 seconds, but the alert comes before replacing the location. If the user does not click 'ok' button in the alert, he can still see the webpage. I want the webpage to move to `about:blank` page, then pops the alert. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: `replace` replaces the current document with a new one. There's nothing on `about:blank` i.e. no code for showing an alert on `about:blank`. If you want to show expire status after `replace` then kindly `replace` to a custom page where there's an `alert` etc.

Answer (score 2):

For one thing, you can't open `about:blank` and run custom JS after that, and in general you can't run code after changing `window.location` (and because of how the event loop is set up, some code after a change statement gets executed).

You could make a custom `/expired` page on your site that runs `alert(" ... ")` when the custom blank page loads.

Also keep in mind that some people have JavaScript disabled, and could override what `window.location.replace` does via a userscript.

Another alternative (that could still be overridden by a userscript, but everything can) is to delete everything on the webpage:

```js
<SCRIPT>
    function checkExpiry() {
        var now_ = new Date();
        var expiry = new Date("<?php echo $expiry ?>")
        if (now_ > expiry) {
            document.body.innerHTML = "";
            document.head.innerHTML = "";
            setTimeout(() => alert("The webpage is expired."), 0); // force alert() to the end of the callstack so body & head get cleared before alert
        }            
    }
    setInterval(function () { checkExpiry(); }, 15 * 1000);
</SCRIPT>
```

Here's an example of that running (check dev tools to see it all goes away):

```js
function expire() {
  document.body.innerHTML = "";
  document.head.innerHTML = "";
  setTimeout(() => alert("The webpage is expired."), 0);
}
```

```html
<h1>This is a webpage</h1>
<p>not really, but you get the point</p>
<button onclick="expire()">run "expire" function manually</button>
<p>check dev tools (inside the iframe) after expiring to see that this is all gone</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for an advice! However, I can still see the contents of the original webpage when the alert pops up... The webpage becomes empty once I click enter in the alert.

Comment: If you're having that issue, try increasing the number from `0`ms to `250`ms in the second argument of the `setTimeout` function call

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not possible, as you cannot run code on another arbitrary webpage. If you want the page to be blank, a workaround would be to do something like setting `<body>`'s opacity to 0

```html
<script>
    function checkExpiry() {
        let now = new Date();
        let expiry = new Date("<?php echo $expiry ?>")
        if (now > expiry) {
            document.body.style.opacity = 0
            alert("The webpage is expired.");
        }            
    }
    setInterval(function () { checkExpiry(); }, 15 * 1000);
</script>
```